# c# MVC: ajax beginform not working after call from ajax actionlink

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

i have problem with call ajax.actionlink.
in *index* view i have a 2 buttons. By default is call *Editor* method in *TestController* and ajax.beginform work correctly, if i click hyperlink (ajax) to switch view and i click other hyperlink to come back to previous view with beginform, then beginform dont work. Why and how to fix that? Code is below.

Index view

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title> Test? </title>

    <link href="~/Content/Admin/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    @Ajax.ActionLink( "T1", "Editor", "Test", new AjaxOptions(){ UpdateTargetId = "ii2" } )
    @Ajax.ActionLink( "T2", "Test1", "Test2", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "ii2" })

<div id="ii2">

</div>

</body>
```

Editor view

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> index </th>
        <th> name </th>
        <th> action </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="iTest1" >
        @Html.Action( "Table", "Test" )
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        @Html.Action( "TableAdd", "Test" )
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Table view

```
@using Domain.Entity
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Entity.Language>

@foreach (Language l in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td> @l.Index </td>
        <td> @l.Name </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
}
```

TableAdd view

```
@model Domain.Entity.Language
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( "Add", "Test", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "iTest1" }))
{
    <th> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Index) </th>
    <th> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </th>
    <th> <input type="submit" value="submit"/> </th>
}
```

Test controller

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private ILanguageRepository _repository = null;

    public TestController(ILanguageRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View( );
    }

    public ActionResult Editor()
    {
        return PartialView( "Editor" );
    }

    public ActionResult Add(Language l)
    {
        _repository.Add( l, true );
        return Table();
    }

    public ActionResult Table(IEnumerable<Language> items = null)
    {
        if (items == null)
            items = _repository.Languages;
        return PartialView( "Table", items );
    }

    public ActionResult TableAdd( Language item )
    {
        return PartialView("TableAdd", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do yorr mean _then beginform dont work_ What does not work?What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens? What errors are you getting?

Comment: view is normally displayed after changed but if i click submit in begin form nothing happens, like as empty button <button> </button>

Comment: @neuser Your question is confusing. You have 2 links on Index. You click one and it takes you to Editor view. Editor view has form. You say the form works the first time but not the second time. Am I correct? How are you coming to the form to the second time?

Comment: yes, at call this same view at second time, beginform dont works

Comment: i edited the ask and at first time is generated empty tag: <div id="ii2"> </div>, if i click ajax actionlink **T1** then will be generated view with beginform into tag, and if i click submit, then nothing happens